# How to copy file on end of build in visual studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I am linking with the .lib file of external library in my program with #pragma, only if some preprocessor macro is defined. I want to copy the dll file of the library to specified location upon the build is finished if the same preprocessor macro is defined. Is this possible

Comment: Yes. It is possible. *How* to do it depends on your build system though.

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio allows you to [specify custom build events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/specifying-custom-build-events-in-visual-studio), but it has no provision to *conditionally* perform those steps.

What you can do, instead, is to create different configurations: One, that both defines the preprocessor symbol, and copies the DLL on successful build, and another one, that does neither of those.

You can use [property pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/ide/working-with-project-properties) to keep dependent settings (e.g. the preprocessor definition and the post-build event) in a single place. This eases build management, especially when using multiple configurations.